# Entity Framework issue when saving an entity object

Tags: c#, entity-framework

Scenario: Intranet app. Windows authentication. EF 6.1.3. Databases: SQL Server Compact Edition and MS Access. VS Studio 2013.

The solution has 3 projects:

EnqueteWeb.UI - ASP.NET web application;
EnqueteWeb.Dominio - class library for the application domain;
ControleDeAcessoGeral - class library to get data of the user logged from Active Directory, and include/update/delete/list some users that perform some special actions on the app.
As the access control to the app is based on a SQL Server Compact Edition database, I have EntityFramework installed in **ControleDeAcessoGeral**. I want to have all the methods regarding to users in a class in this project. And so I did it.

This **ControleDeAcessoGeral** project is defined like this:

Aplicacao
 - Corp.cs (methods to deal with Active Directory stuff)
 - UsuariosApp.cs (methods to deal with the SQL Server CE database)
Contexto
 - DBControleDeAcesso.cs (defines the context)
 - InicializaControleDeAcesso.cs (fill in initial data to the
   DBControleDeAcesso database)
Entidades
 - Perfil.cs (profiles that a user can have on the app)
 - Usuarios.cs (users that may perform some actions on the app)
 - UsuarioAD.cs (Active Directory user and its data)

The DBControleDeAcesso.cs class has the following code:

```
using ControleDeAcessoGeral.Models.Entidades;
using System.Data.Entity;
using System.Data.Entity.ModelConfiguration.Conventions;

namespace ControleDeAcessoGeral.Models.Contexto
{
    public class DBControleDeAcesso : DbContext
    {
        public DBControleDeAcesso() : base("ControleDeAcessoContext") { }

        public DbSet<Perfil> Perfis { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Usuario> Usuarios { get; set; }

        protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            modelBuilder.Conventions.Remove<PluralizingTableNameConvention>();
        }
    }
}
```

The entities classes are the following:
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;

```
namespace ControleDeAcessoGeral.Models.Entidades
{
    public class Usuario
    {
        [Key]
        public string Logon { get; set; }
        public string Nome { get; set; }
        [Display(Name="Órgão")]
        public string Orgao { get; set; }
        public string Email { get; set; }

        [StringLength(maximumLength: 4)]
        public string Depto { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "Perfis")]
        public virtual List<Perfil> Perfis { get; set; }

        public Usuario()
        {
            this.Perfis = new List<Perfil>();
        }
    }
}  

using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;

namespace ControleDeAcessoGeral.Models.Entidades
{
    public class Perfil
    {
        [Key]
        public int Id { get; set; }

        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Por favor, informe o NOME DO perfil.")]
        [StringLength(maximumLength: 25)]
        public string Nome { get; set; }

        [StringLength(maximumLength: 255)]
        [Display(Name = "Descrição")]
        public string Descricao { get; set; }

        public virtual List<Usuario> Usuarios { get; set; }

        public Perfil()
        {
            this.Usuarios = new List<Usuario>();
        }
    }
}
```

And the UsuariosApp.cs class is as bellow (for the sake of brevity, I'll show only the methods that concerns to the issue):

```
using ControleDeAcessoGeral.Models.Contexto;
using ControleDeAcessoGeral.Models.Entidades;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data.Entity;
using System.Linq;

namespace ControleDeAcessoGeral.Models.Aplicacao
{
    public class UsuariosApp
    {
        private DBControleDeAcesso db { get; set; }

        public UsuariosApp()
        {
            db = new DBControleDeAcesso();
        }

        public void SalvarUsuario(Usuario usuario)
        {
            db.Usuarios.Add(usuario);
            db.SaveChanges();
        }

        public Perfil LocalizarPerfil(int id)
        {
            return db.Perfis.Find(id);
        }
    }
}
```

The action that tries to save a user (Usuarios.cs) in the SQL Server CE database is in **AdministracaoController** and has the following code:

```
using ControleDeAcessoGeral.Models.Aplicacao;
using ControleDeAcessoGeral.Models.Entidades;
using EnqueteWeb.UI.Models;
using EnqueteWeb.UI.ViewModels;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web.Mvc;

namespace EnqueteWeb.UI.Controllers
{
    public class AdministracaoController : Controller
    {

        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult CriarUsuarioNaApp(UsuarioViewModel model)
        {
            foreach (var item in model.PerfisSelecionados)
            {
                Perfil perfil = new UsuariosApp().LocalizarPerfil(item);
                model.Usuario.Perfis.Add(perfil);
            }
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                new UsuariosApp().SalvarUsuario(model.Usuario);
                return RedirectToAction("Usuarios");
            }
            return View(model);
        }
    }
}
```

So, when this action **CriarUsuarioNaApp** is invoked and the method **SalvarUsuario(model.Usuario)** runs, the following error occurs:

*An entity object cannot be referenced by multiple instances of IEntityChangeTracker*

I've read a few about this on web but, unfortunately, I still couldn't make it works.

Hope a wise and good soul will show me the way.

Thanks for your attention.

Paulo Ricardo Ferreira

Comment: I scanned your post a few times and couldn't figure out what error you're seeing. Can you be more clear with the error?

Comment: @Visser, sorry about that. I've just forgot to write the error message. Thanks for your attention

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem arises from the fact that you do not dispose of the first `DbContext` instance (from which you load the profile entities) prior to attaching said entities to the second `DbContext` instance.

To fix (and some additional suggestions):

1. have `UsuariosApp` implement `IDisposable` and dispose your instance of the `DbContext` `db` when disposing `UsuariosApp`
2. wrap your newly-disposable `UsuariosApp` instance in a `using` statement and use this single instance for both your `Perfil` loading and `Usuario` saving logic
3. optimize `Perfil` loading by loading all values with single call
4. validate `ModelState.IsValid` immediately

Something like this:

```
public class UsuariosApp : IDisposable
{
    private DBControleDeAcesso db { get; set; }

    public UsuariosApp()
    {
        db = new DBControleDeAcesso();
    }

    public void SalvarUsuario(Usuario usuario)
    {
        db.Usuarios.Add(usuario);
        db.SaveChanges();
    }

    public Perfil LocalizarPerfil(int id)
    {
        return db.Perfis.Find(id);
    }

    public IEnumerable<Perfil> LocalizarPerfiles( IEnumerable<int> ids )
    {
        return db.Perfils.Where( p => ids.Contains( p.Id ) )
            .ToArray();
    }

    private bool _disposed = false;

    protected virtual void Dispose( bool disposing )
    {
        if( _disposed )
        {
            return;
        }

        if( disposing )
        {
            db.Dispose();
        }

        _disposed = true;
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        Dispose( true );
        GC.SuppressFinalize( this );
    }
}

public ActionResult CriarUsuarioNaApp( UsuarioViewModel model )
{
    // validate model state first
    if( ModelState.IsValid )
    {
        // use single, disposable repo/uow instance
        using( var uapp = new UsuariosApp() )
        {
            // get all profiles in a single call, no loop required
            var perfils = uapp.LocalizarPerfiles( model.PerfisSelecionados );

            model.Usuario.Perfis.AddRange( perfils );

            uapp.SalvarUsuario( model.Usuario );
        }

        return RedirectToAction( "Usuarios" );
    }

    return View( model );
}
```

Let me know if that doesn't solve your problem.

Comment: thanks a lot. It worked perfectly. And I still got a bonus: that method LocalizarPerfiles.